# how to write the identity function in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a function with type like this:

```
functionX :: [String] -> ([Integer] -> [Integer])
```

It is kind of like a mapping function that maps a specific String to a function with type as so.
Because I need to handle the call functionX [], which I think this call should return something called identity function, or whatever, how can I write it?

Comment: You might profit from one of the books for people new to Haskell.  I like [Learn You a Haskell For Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) and [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/).  Both are free to read online.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled.  Your functionX takes a list of strings but returns a single function.  Or maybe you actually mean:

"functionX :: String -> Int -> Int"

Then you can apply it to a list of strings and integers using zipWith.  By the way, your brackets are not needed; "->" is right-associative.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136338/uses-for-haskell-id-function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`id` is predefined as the identity function in haskell.  It has type `id :: a -> a`.

If you wanted, you could define your own easily:

```
myIdentityFunction :: a -> a
myIdentityFunction a = a
```

Comment: So the type of the identity function is [Integer] -> [Integer] ?

Comment: I may be remembering incorrectly, but i think haskell defaults to generic types

Comment: @baboonWorksFine: Cogwheel's right.  The identity function's return type is parameterized by its input type.  Since it doesn't do anything with the input other than return it, it places no constraints on the input's type.  In Haskell, lowercase letters in a type signature (like `id :: a -> a`) indicates that those symbols stand for a type parameter, rather than a concrete type like `String` or `Integer`.

Comment: all right, the thing is, how can I handle the call "functionX []"

Comment: Then just handle the other case separately : `function (x:xs) = ...`

Comment: In Haskell these types are not called 'generic' but rather 'polymorphic'. In the context of Haskell, 'generic' means something else entirely.