# Function taking one parameter and returning it

Tags: c++, functional-programming

There is something that has been on my mind for a long time now. Just consider this function:

```
template<typename T>
T foo(const T& value)
{
    return value;
}
```

It's the simplest possible function wrapper for any given value. However, I've been wondering whether it has a "standard name" (that many would recognize, like functions such as map, filter, sqrt, etc...). And are they well-known problems that require to use such a function?

Comment: Here are good examples on using id function on [Haskell]. I know this is for C++, but the examples there on where and when use id function are really good: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136338/uses-for-haskell-id-function

Comment: @hectorg87 Nice examples, I think I can see part of it usefulness in functional programming. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome. Since you have higher order functions in C++ too, it's not crazy to think you could use identity this way too, however **I think** that it's not the most common way to code in C++.

Comment: Yeah, C++ allows functional programming, but it's not the main paradigm C++ was designed for. It's probably more useful in LISP dialects and siblings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In principle it's an identity function, but in practice it forces a copy of the argument.

So, if `T` has value semantics, it's still a real identity.
Otherwise, it's a cloning function.

A perfect identity would be

```
template<typename T>
const T& identity(const T& value)
{
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Right, my pass-by-value example was quite not good. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's an identity function. It's useful, for example, for when you have to pass a projection to some other function and don't want any projection. No, not terribly useful, but that's the best you can get from a function that basically does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Without any changes to the parameter inside the function, I'm not sure it has any programming nomenclature.

You also can't say it's a full-on identity as the object returned isn't the same object, since you return by value.

I'd say it's a **cloning function**.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function) for *identity functions*

Comment: For reference, SO usually prefers answers to be somewhat self-contained (athough links to references are naturally welcome). Reference on [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). It wasn't my downvote btw, but I thought you'd like to know.