# Does the identity function in Clojure have the same usage and purpose as the id function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, clojure, identity, lenses

In Clojure we have the `identity` function. It [is used as follows](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/identity):

```
user=> (filter identity [1 2 3 nil 4 false true 1234])
(1 2 3 4 true 1234)

user=> (partition-by identity (sort "abcdaabccc"))
((\a \a \a) (\b \b) (\c \c \c \c) (\d))
```

From what I can see in Haskell - `id` [is used when using lenses](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-1.1.1/docs/Control-Lens.html) and is [used in other higher order functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136338/uses-for-haskell-id-function).

My question is (apart from the obvious Type system differences) **Does the `identity` function in Clojure have the same usage and purpose as the `id` function in Haskell?**

Why I ask is when I look at [the following example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/markhibberd/lens-talk-clojure/master/lens/script.org) of a [Lens in Clojure](https://github.com/markhibberd/lens-talk-clojure/blob/master/lens/src/lens/core.clj) - we see `Id` defined in terms of `functor`:

```
(defprotocol Functor
    (fmap [functor f] "fmap :: f a -> (a -> b) -> f b"))

;; data Id a = Id { runId :: a }
(defrecord Id [runId]
    Functor
   (fmap [functor f]
        (Id. (f (:runId functor)))))
```

So I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: The definition of `Id` in clojure equals the `Identity` functor in Haskell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`id`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:id) function in Haskell is the [I combinator of lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus#Informal_description). It is the trival function:

```
-- | Identity function.
id :: a -> a
id x = x
```

It is [useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136338/uses-for-haskell-id-function) the way that 0 or the empty list are useful.

The [`identity`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/identity) function in Clojure is equivalent in that it returns its argument unmodified.

```
(defn identity
  "Returns its argument."
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  [x] x)
```

Other notions of e.g [`Identity` monads](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-1.1.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Identity.html) and so forth are not directly connected to the `id` function.