# Implicitly get the value of the own variable

Tags: php, haskell

Is there any way to get the **current**, after **previous** value of a variable while setting it?
I mean:

```
$x = 10
$x = id() + 20; // 30

function id() {
   return THE_VARIABLE_VALUE; // 10
}
```

Or do I need be explicit and say (?):

```
$x = 10
$x = id($x) + 20; // 30

function id($x) {
   return $x; // 10
}
```

My question is:

In PHP, can I get implicitly the value of a variable?

*id* is trying to simulate the very known *id* function, that returns the own element:

```
id = (xs) -> xs
id 1 -- 1
id 'k' -- k
```

Comment: Afaik this is not possible in PHP. I don't know for what this can be useful either. Is better and cleaner code if you give paramters into the function and get a return value.

Comment: A variable contains one value. It doesn't store its own history. For such purposes, we have data structures such as arrays which you can use to implement such functionality. Also, I have never heard of the "very known id function". Are you referring to auto_increment of some sort?

Comment: @N.B. I believe his is refering to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136338/uses-for-haskell-id-function i cant say i am any the wiser for reading it though!

Comment: @Steve - thanks for the link, I must admit that I'm in the same boat as you after reading it :)

Comment: In Haskell, just like in PHP, `id` can't magically guess what variable you're talking about. It has to be passed a value, like `x`, and then it returns that same value. You can't just call `id` and get 10 because you were thinking of 10 a minute ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can use functions directly as the type of their return value, so you can do operations and function calls on them. On my localhost I have php 5.4 and I can do stuff like `$myarray_element = get_my_array()[0];` or `$mynumber = get_my_array_element()+10;`. You can't do things like`get_my_array_element()++;` or `$var = get_my_array_element()++;`.

Answer (score 0):

Well... for simple math, you could use the built in "modify this variable" operators:

```
$x += 20;
$x -= 10;
$x *= 5;
$x /= 3;
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here, so other than that not much I can say. Maybe try explaining what your goal is here?