# Of what use is identity function in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

What is the use of identity function? It simply returns the same value. Hence, instead of putting `(identity x)`, why not simply put `x`? Could someone give some examples of using identity function in Racket/Scheme? There are no examples on these documentation page: [https://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/beginner.html#%28def.*htdp-beginner.*%28%28lib._lang%2Fhtdp-beginner..rkt%29.*identity%29%29*](https://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/beginner.html#%28def._htdp-beginner._%28%28lib._lang%2Fhtdp-beginner..rkt%29._identity%29%29)  and  [https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html?q=identity#%28def.%28%28lib._racket%2Ffunction..rkt%29._identity%29%29](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html?q=identity#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ffunction..rkt%29._identity%29%29)

Comment: There a few related questions about using the identity function in other languages, the idea is probably the same, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136338/uses-for-haskell-id-function or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421502/is-there-any-good-example-of-use-cases-for-angular-identity?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Same could be asked about constant functions ;).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `identity` function is mostly useful as an argument to certain higher-order functions (functions which take functions as arguments) when a function performs a certain sort of mapping customized by its argument, and you wish to pass the value through unchanged.<sup>†</sup>

One extremely common idiom in Scheme/Racket is using `(filter identity ...)` to remove all `#f` values from a list:

```
> (filter identity '(1 2 #f 4))
'(1 2 4)
```

This works because `filter` applies the provided function to each of the elements of a list, then discards values that result in `#f`. By using `identity`, the values themselves are checked. In this sense, `identity` is the functional “no-op”.

You may sometimes see this idiom spelled `(filter values ...)` instead of `(filter identity ...)` because `values` happens to be the identity function when provided with one argument, and it comes from `racket/base` instead of `racket/function`. I prefer the version that uses `identity` explicitly, though, because I think it is a little bit clearer what’s going on.

---

<sup>† This description of the identity function comes from [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3136376/465378) for the Haskell equivalent question.</sup>

Comment: is there anyway to pass #f  instead the idenity function?

Comment: @X10D No, there isn’t. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @X10D If you want to pass a function always returning false you can do (lambda (x) #f)